# How to get element indexing using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some element in body. I want to know their indexing like div indexing should be 1 and span its indexing should be 2. How to start find

```
$(function(){
var id= document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(i=0; i<id.length;i++){
alert(id[i])
}})

<body>
<div></div>
<span></span>
<p></p>
<strong></strong>
</body>
```

Comment: Isn't `i + 1` the number you're looking for?

Comment: it should start with '0'

Comment: `<body>` should be `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very easily in jQuery (I can see you're using it), by using this code:

```
$(function(){
   $.each($('body *'), function(i, v) { // All elements within the <body> tag
      var index = (i + 1); // zero-based index, so plus 1.
      console.log(index);
   });
})
```

jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/u7kWF/

Pure JS example:

```
var id = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'); // Get all tags within <body>
for(i=0; i<id.length;i++){
     console.log(id[i]); // The tag - <div>, <span>, <p>, <strong>
     console.log(i + 1); // The index - 1,2,3,4
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u7kWF/1/

Comment: can you please do this using javascript

Comment: You've got the jQuery library, as you're using $(function(){, but I'll do it in plain JS too.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below, It will help you...

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/136/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div></div>
<span></span>
<p></p>
<strong></strong>
</body>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(function(){
var id= document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");;
for(i=0; i<id.length;i++){
    alert(" Tagname : " + id[i].tagName + "  Index : " + i)
}})
```